# Add xsd files to the data directory of the office clickonce deployment

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vsto, clickonce

I have the deployed excel document solution to the server using clickonce. xsd files are not being deployed though i have added these files in my solution and kept the properties as

> BuidAction:Content and Copy to Output Directory:Copy Always

on client machine. I have also added xml files which are deployed successfully on client machine in data directory with same properties as defined above.

Also i Have kept the Customization updates(Publish Tab) property to Check everytime the customization runs still when i publish new vwersion i m getting following error

> Customization could not be loaded because the application domain could
>   not be created

Any suggessions ?

Comment: This exception can be because of many things. Do you have .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

With VSTO applications and ClickOnce, you can not specify where the files are deployed like you can with a client application. XML files are automatically deployed to the DataDirectory whether you want them to be or not, and XSD files will not be deployed to the DataDirectory, they will be included locally.

So if you need them to be included in the same folder, I recommend you rename the xml files to .xml.txt so they will be deployed with the rest of the application instead of to the Data Directory, and then have your add-in rename them when it starts up. Will that work?